# Every morphism in Set is regular

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to prove that every morphism in the category **Set** is regular, that is, that for every set-function $f:A\to B$ there exists a function $g:B\to A$ such that $f\circ g\circ f=f$. The assumption is that $A\neq\varnothing $, because otherwise $B=\varnothing$.

Define an equivalence relation on $A$: for any $x,y\in A$, $x\sim y\Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$. In the set $A/\sim$ choose an equivalence class representative for each class $[x]$, then define a function $g:B\to A, g(f(x))=x'$, where $x\sim x'$ and if $b\in B$ is not in the image of $f$ then just map it anywhere. That way I can track equivalent elements of $A$ and eventually map them into the right element of $B$.

The way I have 'constructed' $g$ is not unique, but is this construction valid at all and have I actually proved the proposition? Did I assume some form of axiom of choice?

Comment: In ZFC the following statements are equivalent 1. The axiom of choice and 2. Every surjective map, $f:X\to Y$ has a splitting ie. a maps, $s:Y\to X$ such that $f\circ s=id_{Y}$. Combine that with the fact that every map in set may be factored as a surjection followed by an injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's valid, and proves the proposition.

Yes, you have implicitly used the axiom of choice when simultaneously fixed one $x'$ in each equivalence class of $\sim$, which is needed for the definition of $g$.